# If $\varphi : X \to Y$ is a regular map of affine algebraic sets and $Z \subset Y$ is closed, then $\varphi ^{−1} (Z) = \mathcal V(\varphi^ ∗ (I(Z)))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose that $\varphi : X \to Y$ is a regular map of affine algebraic sets and $Z \subset Y$ is a closed set. Then $\varphi^{−1} (Z) = \mathcal V(\varphi^* (I(Z)))$.

$Z$ is a closed set, i.e. $Z$ is the set of common zeros of some polynomials.
Suppose $\varphi : X \to Y$ is given by $\varphi=(f_1,...,f_m)$, $I(Z)=\{g\in k[Y]|g(Z)=0\}$. Then $\mathcal V(\varphi^* (I(Z)))=\mathcal V(g(f_1,...,f_m))$.

To solve this problem, I think I should describe these 2 set accurately, but I have no idea.

Any hints?

Comment: Please use the appropriate math mode symbols like \varphi and \to instead of copy/pasting those characters from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preimage of the closed subscheme $Z\subset Y$ under the map $X\rightarrow Y$ is the fiber product $X\times_Y Z$. Now you assumed that $Y$ is affine, so let us write $Y=\text{Spec}(k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a})$, $Z=\text{Spec}(k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{b})$ and $X=\text{Spec}(k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]/\mathfrak{c})$. The fiber product of affine schemes corresponds to the tensor product of the corresponding rings, i.e.
$$X\times_Y Z= \text{Spec}\left((k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]/\mathfrak{c}\otimes_{k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a} }k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{b}   \right).$$
This yields the result you want.